# Firefox shows NaN in conversion of millisecond to date

Tags: javascript

The code is:

```
var converted_timedate = Date.parse(tqaed_date); //tqaed_date=2015-08-03T14:44:39Z
var converted_int_timedate = parseInt(converted_timedate, 10); 
var convert_into_date = new Date(converted_int_timedate); 
var gettime_converteddate = convert_into_date.getTime() + ((-final_diff) * 1000 * 60); //final_diff=0
```

In chrome it is working but in FF it shows `NaN` any mistake or suggestion?

Comment: Works fine for me: `(new Date(parseInt(Date.parse('2015-08-03T14:44:39Z'), 10))).getTime() + 0;` (Firefox 39)

Comment: The code you posted works in Firefox 39.

Comment: @Boldewyn bt I am still getting `NaN`..

Comment: I am also working in FF 39 but still getting same err

Comment: Where exactly does it show the `NaN`? In the console or the rendered HTML?

Comment: in both @Boldewyn .. m checking using debugger

Comment: If you paste the line that I posted above in the console's command line, and it works there, the problem must lie somewhere else. The `tqaed_date`: Does it have the upper-case `T` in the middle?

Comment: @Boldewyn I have a posted same line `var fetched_date = fetchedtime.split(" ")[0];
        var fetched_time = fetchedtime.split(" ")[1];
        var fetched_datetime = fetched_date + "T" + fetched_time + "Z";
        var convert_into_date = new Date(parseInt(Date.parse(fetched_datetime), 10)).getTime() + 0;` now getting problem in `var convert_into_date`..it shows NaN

Comment: @Boldewyn it is now working..did "/" instead of "-" n used ur line..thnx for help

Comment: OK, great! My pleasure!